# Why need for using JDBC write Class.forName(...) for each connection?

Tags: java, jdbc

If I want to connect to database I should write code like this:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/mysidorservicename", "sysdba", "password123");
```

Why should I load the concrete driver before I connect to database? The result of the `Class.forName` statement is ignored - the loaded class is obviously not associated with the `DriverManager`. Can I just load all drivers used for different databases in moment of start application and will not write `Class.forName` code before each connection?

Comment: There are many JDBC for that you need to specify witch JDBC you are using, this is why you use that

Comment: You don't need to write it before each connection. You need to execute it once, and with modern drivers you don't even need the `Class.forName()` anymore.

Comment: Recommended reading: [Oracle tutorial on establishing a connection with JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html). Especially the part where it says "In previous versions of JDBC..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Older `DriverManager` implementations (before JDBC 4.0, which was park of JDK 6), required drivers to have a static block that would register them to the `DriverManager`. Static blocks are called once when the class is loaded by the driver manager. To your question - it doesn't really matter where you load these classes, as long as you load the drivers before attempting to use them.

Since JDBC 4.0 (which is, as mentioned above, a part of JDK 6), you don't have to call `Class.forName` at all, though. To quote the [`DriverManager`'s javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html):

> The `DriverManager` methods `getConnection` and `getDrivers` have been enhanced to support the Java Standard Edition Service Provider mechanism. JDBC 4.0 Drivers must include the file META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver. This file contains the name of the JDBC drivers implementation of java.sql.Driver. For example, to load the my.sql.Driver class, the META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver file would contain the entry [etc..]

In layman's words, it's up to the driver to register itself to declare it provides a JDBC service for a given connection string, and you can just remove the `Class.forName` calls from your code.